# Axiomatic definition of sin and cos?

Tags: trigonometry, axioms

I look for possiblity to define **sin**/**cos** through algebraic relations without involving power series, integrals, differential equation and geometric intuition.

Is it possible to define  **sin** and **cos** through some axioms?

Like:

$$\sin 0 = 0, \cos 0 = 1$$
$$\sin \pi/2 = 1, \cos \pi/2 = 0$$
$$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$$
$$\sin(x+2\pi n) = \sin x, \cos(x+2\pi n) = \cos x$$
$$\sin(-x)=-\sin x, \cos(-x) = \cos x \text{ for } x \in [-\pi;0]$$
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos x$$

and be able to prove trigonometric school equations?

What additions are required to prove continuity and uniqueness of such functions and analysis properties like:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0$$
or
$$\sin ' x = \cos x$$
or
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} = \arcsin x$$

**PS** In Walter Rudin book "Principles of Mathematical analysis"  **sin** and **cos** introduced through power series.

In Solomon Feferman book "The Number Systems: Foundations of Algebra and Analysis" I see system derived from integral definition.

Comment: How would you define $\pi$? I mean, without geometry or trigonometric functions.

Comment: I see you have rejected the approach of definition by differential equations, but of course the second-order constant coefficient ODE (with appropriate initial conditions) would be a natural approach.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226051/to-whom-do-we-owe-this-construction-of-angles-and-trigonometry). I plan on expanding on it to define $\sin$ and $\cos$ for real numbers.

Comment: I answer to myself: $\pi$ can be defined as $6\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1/n^2)}$. But trying to define exp, sin or cos from this deos not look nice...

Comment: @ajotatxe *How would you define π?* In Feferman book it defined from integral of $\sqrt(1-x^2)$. More likely that π have sense only in analysis. We can start with any period. I currently can't imaging differential equation with sin/cos or other restriction that defines π unambiguously...

Comment: i wonder what is left to define these functions?

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078377/defining-sine-and-cosine)

Comment: @gavenkoa $\pi$ is the smallest positive real such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{i\pi}n\right)^n=-1$, I guess. (Or you could get a more complicated definition from geometry, perhaps involving supremums of infimums of lengths of stuff.)

Comment: There's [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078377/defining-sine-and-cosine/) question, which gives a perfectly good definition.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Is the pi in the equation maybe supposed to be a variable instead?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To quote [a previous answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115873):

> Robison, "A new approach to circular functions, π, and lim sin(x)/x", Math. Mag. 41.2 (March 1968), 66–70 [[jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689051)].
>
> In this paper it is shown that the addition law for cosine (and a couple other simple assumptions) uniquely determines cosine and sine.

(This is the paper I cite most often on StackExchange.)

If you don't have access to jstor (and don't want to sign up for their free 3-papers-at-a-time deal), you could try [this other answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/834572) to a closely related question about exponentiation, in which I adapted Robison's proof to give the following functional characterization of sine and cosine:

> *Proposition 1.*  Suppose $C,S\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfy these conditions:
>
> 1. $C$ and $S$ are continuous;
> 2. $C(u-v) = C(u)C(v)+S(u)S(v)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb R$;
> 3. $S(u-v) = S(u)C(v)-C(u)S(v)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb R$;
> 4. $C$ and $S$ are not both identically zero.
>
> Then there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that
>
> $$ C(u) = \cos(\lambda u) \quad\text{and}\quad S(u) = \sin(\lambda u)
> \text{ .} $$

You'll note that I just took continuity as an axiom, which was convenient and natural in the context of that other question; Robison proves continuity from weaker but less intuitive axioms — if memory serves, the key one is that cosine has a smallest positive root, i.e., there exists $p>0$ such that $C(p)=0$ and $C(x)\ne0$ for $0 < x < p$ — which might serve your purposes better.

(Oh, and since there's some question about degrees and radians and all that: Robison takes the normalization $p=1$, proves that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{S(x)}{x}$ exists, then defines $\pi = 2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{S(x)}{x}$, and then defines $\sin(x) = S(\frac{2x}{\pi})$, and similarly for $\cos$.  This manoeuvre amounts to defining $\pi$ by the condition $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, very much like we sometimes define $e$ by the condition $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$.)

Comment: I gave some more conditions that specify radians, if you like. (For some reason, I find inequalities more pleasing than limits. Perhaps because inequalities are more elementary of an idea.)

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer.  Nice observations.  You might also be interested to know that $f(x) = e^x$ is the only function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f(x)\ge x+1$.

Comment: $e^x\ge x+1$ is my favorite inequality, actually. It's surprisingly powerful — for example, it lets you prove that $\ln2=1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb$ _without using calculus_! (You need the squeeze theorem at the very end, though.)

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 14):

From what you do not want that pretty much leaves functional equations.

There seems to be a system of two functional equations for sine and cosine: ([link](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funktionalgleichung#Sinus_und_Kosinus))

$$
\Theta(x+y)=\Theta(x)\Theta(y)-\Omega(x)\Omega(y) \\
\Omega(x+y)=\Theta(x)\Omega(y)+\Omega(x)\Theta(y)
$$

Comment: @ajotatxe Through power series?

Comment: Via $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$ plus some extra condition $f(0) = 1$? Not sure if that is enough for complex argument. Hm.

Comment: There seems to be a road from there to the functional equations for cosine and sine.

Comment: Since these formulas hold for angles measured in degrees or radians alike, could there still be some ambiguity? I.e., would this only allow us to know $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$?

Comment: For the exponential function one needs a value as well, like $f(1) = e$ and it seems Lebesgue measurability ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations)). As these seem to be derived from the exponential function, I would expect extra conditions as well. But I lack a reference for a sound solution of the functional equations system.

Comment: @mvw My answer links to a more thorough treatment than German Wikipedia gives.  Though now that I notice (belatedly) that you've given the same answer I rushed to give, I wonder if I should just move my links into a comment here...

Comment: @StevenTaschuk No problem. Keep it like it is. Yours adds a good reference.

Comment: The functions $\Theta(x)=0$ and $\Omega(x)=0$ also satisfy the equations.

Comment: @PyRulez See StevenTaschuk's answer below, prop. 1 for the extra conditions.

Comment: $e^x\sin x$ and $e^x\cos x$ work, if I recall correctly. Probably why Taschuk dealt with the difference formulae.

Answer (score 5):

A definition not involving power series, integrals, differential equations, or geometric intuition is:$$\cos x+\mathrm i\sin  x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{\mathrm ix}{n}\right)^{\!n}\quad(x\in\Bbb R).$$

Comment: You can actually get that definition through geometric intuition.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: How?

Comment: @cfh Basically, because $\sin\epsilon\approx\epsilon$ and $\cos\epsilon\approx1$ for small $\epsilon$, we have $1+\frac{ix}n\approx\cos\frac x n+\sin\frac x n$. Using De Moivre, we get $(1+\frac{ix}n)^n\approx\cos x+\sin x$, and the approximation becomes equality taking the limit.

Comment: @cfh As for De Moivre, let's define $R_\theta(z)$ to mean $z$ rotated of $\theta$ degrees. Notice that, because of the parallelogram rule, $R_\theta(w+z)=R_\theta(w)+R_\theta(z)$. In addition, $R_\theta(i)=iR_\theta(1)$, and $R_\theta(1)=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Putting this all together, we end up with $R_\theta(z)=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)z$. De Moivre's rule is just the fact that $R_\theta(R_\theta(R_\theta(\dots R_\theta(1)\dots)))=R_{n\theta}(1)$, with $n$ "$R_\theta$"s on the left.

Comment: (First comment is "geometric" because this all has a nice geometric interpretation in the unit circle of the complex plane.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I agree about de Moivre, that's just Euler's formula and has a simply geometric interpretation. For the first part of your argument... eh, I don't quite see the link to geometry, feels much more like calculus to me.

Comment: @cfh $\sin\epsilon\approx\epsilon$ is basically saying that a small arc is well approximated by a line. $\epsilon$ is the length of the arc, and $\sin\epsilon$ is its height. The arc is almost entirely vertical, so…

Answer (score 3):

Other answers give equations that define sine and cosine without specifying the units. If you want radians, you'll want:
\begin{align}
\sin x<x<\tan x&&&x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)
\end{align}
There are other equivalent ways to get radians, such as:
\begin{align}
\sin x&\le x^2+x&x&\in\mathbb R\\
\cos x&<\frac{\sin x}x<1&x&\in(-\pi,\pi)-\{0\}
\end{align}

---

As for getting $\pi$, here's one I just remembered: Let's say you have formulae that define sine and cosine without units. Well, you don't even *need* the right units to define $\pi$!

Call our functions $\sin x^\circ$ and $\cos x^\circ$ (even though they might not be degrees — the $^\circ$ just means "some unit" here). Let the smallest positive root of $\cos x^\circ$ be called $r$.

Well, $\frac\pi4$ is the *unique* number such that:
\begin{align}
\cos x^\circ&>\frac\pi4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{r^2}\right)&x&\in\mathbb R
\end{align}
[Link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xs7gqt9ybe) to a helpful graph to help you see what's going on. Try changing $r$; you'll see the inequality always holds. Try changing $p$; you'll see that this inequality uniquely defines $\pi$.

Comment: Honestly, you're forced to use radians the minute you start thinking about trig inequalities. (Also: Did you know that the local maxima and minima of $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ are precisely at the intersections of the graphs of $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ and $\cos x$? Graph it. This only works for radians, again.) Similarly, the benefits of using $e^x$ for exponentials, with that weird base $e$, becomes apparent once you start dealing with inequalities.

Comment: Calculus is just inequalities disguised. The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a derivative is full of inequalities.

Comment: Note that the appearance of $\pi/2$ in the inequalities is not necessary for the axiomatization (in case one considers $\pi$ to be assuming the consequent) - one can replace it with $1$ or any sufficiently small positive $x$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Right, yes.