# How to develop the concept of trigonometric function & constant $\pi$ without using any kind of geometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am just curious about this, suppose I am an unschooled blind person who has no idea of any kind of geometrical concept in mind (such as angle, triangle, and so on).

And now I want to study a real value $t$ which satisfies the following equation
$$a(t)^2+b(t)^2=1$$
With some luck, I can end up using the same notation like any non-blind person who have studied geometry by defining
$$\sin(t)=a(t)$$
$$\,\cos(t)=b(t).$$
Starting from here, is there a way for me to keep going and develop the notion of $\pi$ purely algebraically?

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [Axiomatic definition of sin and cos?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303044/axiomatic-definition-of-sin-and-cos).

Comment: It is possible to use power series to define sine, cosine etc.(like we do in complex analysis) and then their period/2 to be pi .

Comment: $sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$.  Does that help?

Comment: $\pi$ is the least positive zero of $\sin(t)$

Comment: One thing to note in these comments and the other thread: the answer to your question about doing it "purely algebraicly" is no. You can either develop sine and cosine geometrically, or you can develop them purely analytically (i.e., involving calculus), but just algebra is not enough.